# Spectrum of a closed operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Could someone please explain this fact: if $A$ is a closed operator and $A^{-1}$ is a compact operator, then spectrum of $A$ consist only of eigenvalues?

I forgot to mention that operator $A^{-1}$ is bounded, but $A$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Start by considering $A^{-1}x=\lambda x$ for $\lambda\ne 0$ in order to conclude that $Ax=\frac{1}{\lambda}x$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean that $A$ is a continuous linear bijection on a Banach space .Let $s$ belong to the spectrum of $A$.Let $(v_n)_n$ be a sequence   with  $||v_n||=1$ for each $n$ and with $(||A v_n-s v_n||)_n$ converging to $0$.Now $A^{-1}$ is compact, and $\{A v_n-s v_n\}_n$ is a bounded set ( because the sequence converges to $0$ ) so there exists a subsequence of $(v_n)_n$,which we will call $(w_n)_n$, for which $(A^{-1}(A w_n-s w_n))_n$ $=(w_n-A^{-1} s w_n)_n$ is  convergent  to some $p$ . The continuity of $A$ implies that $(A(w_n-A^{-1} s w_n))_n =$ $(A w_n-s w_n)_n$  converges to $A p$.But $(A w_n-s a_n)_n$ converges to $0$ so $A p=0 , $  and $A^{-1}$ exists, so $A p=0\implies p=0$.Hence $(w_n-A^{-1} s w_n)_n$ converges  to $0$.We use the compactness of $A^{-1}$ again: The bounded sequence $( w_n)_n$ has a subsequence ,which we will call $(x_n)_n$, for which $(A^{-1} s x_n)_n$ converges to some $q$, and since $(x_n-A^{-1} s x_n)_n$ converges to $0$, the sequence $(x_n)_n$ must also converge to $q$.Note that $q\neq 0$ because $||x_n||=1$ for each $n$.Finally we have $A q-s q=$ $\lim_{n\to \infty} A(x_n-A^{-1} s x_n)=0$. So $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Footnote: We note that $q\neq 0$ in case $s=0$, else the sentence $A q-s q=0$  may be equivalent to $A0=0$.

Comment: I guess the OP meant closed operator not necessarily continuous nor densely defined and as far as I know the results also holds for precisely those.

Comment: Exactly.  The operator A is not continuous, but it is densely defined. The domain $A$ is a subset of a Hilbert space.

Comment: In the light of this previously unstated info can my answer be amended in order to work? I don't have time today to work on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I can not obtain the result.